# How can I tell in React when a child/grandchild component has been added or removed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React, I can execute some code when a component updates by placing the code inside the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method. In my case, I need to distinguish between two types of updates. The first is when only props on existing components change (no DOM elements will be added or removed, but the attributes/contents of existing elements may change). The second is when new child components are added/removed (DOM elements will be added or removed).

Consider the below pseudo code; I would want to execute a function when the Component that has a `name` of `list` has one of its children removed, but *not* when any of the children have their `active` prop altered. This is just a generic example, and not specifically the only thing I'm trying to do, otherwise I could tailor my solution to this specific case.

```
<Module>
  <Component name='list' />
    <Component active={true} />
    <Component active={false} />
    <Component active={false} />
  </Component>
</Module>
```

My solution should ideally affect only the `Module` React component without requiring any changes to the Component React component, something like:

```
export default class Module extends React.Component {
  componentDidUpdate() {
    if ('component tree has been altered') {
      // do something
    }
    else {
      // do something else
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

I considered taking the `props.children.length` value and storing it as state, and then if the value changes between renders I know elements have been added/removed, but I don't think this would work when grand children components are added/removed, only direct children.

I feel like there is maybe a solution using the context API, but I'm not too sure what it would be.

Comment: Pass a function from the parent to the child component as a prop, then call that function using the lifecycle methods of the child (componentDidMount, componentWillUnmount). Do you need an example?

Comment: @AbdullahAlsigar Yeah that makes sense, I should be good from here! Thank you. Feel free to add an example so it can be voted/accepted so you can earn some reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two functions to be called when a child is mounted or unmounted, pass the functions as props to the child components.

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
  childMounted() {
    console.log('child mounted')
  }
  childUnmounted() {
    console.log('child un-mounted')
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <ChildComponent mounted={this.childMounted} unmounted={this.childUnmounted} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

In the child components just call the functions inside the life cycle methods.

```
class ChildComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() { this.props.childMounted() }
  componentWillUnmount() { this.props.unmounted() }
  render() { return null; }
}
```